# XML to JSON Conversion seems to add extra backslashes

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

I am trying to convert an xml document to json by using Newtonsoft JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc);
return json;
```

xmlDoc.InnerXml contains

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><fql_query_response xmlns=\"http://api.facebook.com/1.0/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" list=\"true\"><stream_post><message>Tyck till om kampanjen!\r\n\r\n
```

When I do the conversion extra escape characters are added.

```
{\"?xml\":{\"@version\":\"1.0\",\"@encoding\":\"UTF-8\"},\"fql_query_response\":{\"@xmlns\":\"http://api.facebook.com/1.0/\",\"@xmlns:xsi\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\",\"@list\":\"true\", 
{\"message\":\"Tyck till om kampanjen!\\r\\n\\r\\n
```

Why do this happen, and can i prevent it? I could remove the extra characters but it  seems like there is a setting i'm missing or something.

Regards,
David

Comment: You can ignore this escape characters and use `var jsonData = $.parseJSON(responceJSON);` in javaScript to use it if you are using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem with Java some days ago. Its because you are stringifing a stringified JSON. I mean that you are doing something like:

```
(JAVASCRIPT)
var str = JSON.stringify(data);
return JSON.stringify(str);
```